# Is there another desktop environment similar to Unity?

Tags: unity, appmenu

I found out that Unity will be discontinued by Ubuntu so I want to know if there's an available replacement for it. I'm mainly interested in the universal menu bar at the top of Unity (like in macOS), is there another desktop environment that does this?

Comment: Could give a shot for KDE where you can place your menu bar(s) wherever you want